# Use of undeclared identifier "self"

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add a background to my app programmatically. When I try to run my app, it gives me a warning that says, use of undeclared identifier "self". This is my code from the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIImage *background = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"background"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"background"];
  [self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
```

Can someone rewrite the code with the errors fixed and post it?

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after Load

Comment: -1 Post *actual* code. If this is not the *actual code* then take time to update the post. Use *copy and paste* instead of manually typing it.

Comment: I used copy and paste

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: It's a quirk of ObjC that the semi-colon is not illegal and doesn't affect the method definition.

Comment: This question should be closed because it is predicated on a typo and will have no usefulness for future searchers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not illegal, but you should remove the semicolon after `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
}
```

You have unmatched brackets in this line:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background"]; // Corrected
```

Finally, `initWithImage` takes a `UIImage*` as a parameter, so that line should be:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background]; // Corrected
```

Comment: I copied the code wrong. There was no semicolon after that.

Comment: @user2981312 Did you see the part about the unmatched brackets?

Comment: That still doesn't work. Why does it give me the warning, use of undeclared identifier "self"?

Comment: @user2981312 Okay, dumb questions... Are you in a .m file, and are you in an `@implementation` block?

Comment: Yes I am in a .m file and yes, I am in an @implementation block

Comment: @user2981312 Is this the first compiler error or warning you're getting anywhere in the file? Your code works fine on my system with the corrections I provided, so it must be something else about the file that's wrong.

Comment: I am doing a code challenge on Treehouse

Comment: The semicolon doesn't affect the method definition; it's not illegal.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Wow, learn something new every day. :-) I don't think I'll be adopting that particular style into my software, though...

Comment: Indeed, don't; it definitely looks funny. The speculation I've heard is that it's to make copy-pasting from headers easier.